# Looping a array of JSON object having array as property through Handlebars

Tags: json, loops, handlebars.js

I have a data model something like following:

```
var categories = 
{
    Name: "Rollover"
    URLTypeId: 5
    domains: "{"urlId":"ixwCTbjdaIUoMioqFApdtA==","URLName":"mywebsite.COM","StartingPrice":149.99,"StarRating":4}"
}
```

I am defining HandleBar template

```
#each categories
   -- show category
  #each domain
     --- show domain
  /#each
/#each
```

how can I define a handlebar template for the same?

Comment: what you are expecting on rendering. give an example in question.

Comment: Thanks @CydrickT

Comment: Thanks CydrickT for formatting my question properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I achieved it:

```
{{#each categories}}
   {{#domains}}
   {{/domains}}
{{/each}}
```